# Storing a non-unique array in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm brand new to DynamoDB and finding it surprising how "model driven" a schema-less database can be. Anyway, petty snarkiness out of the way, I am wondering how to declare a property in an item which will be an array of values but one which CAN have duplicate values.

Specifically what I'm storing is wordcloud array of emotive words and if a particular word is used more than once then I want to know that. My simple answer was to have an attribute/property called **wordsPositive** which would be set as type "SS" but it appears this will not allow for duplicate array elements.

The error I get when trying is:

> 400: Input collection [better, excellent, best, important, good, success, best, creative, powerful, benefits] contains duplicates.]

Looking at the AWS web interface at a record which did not have duplicates I can see that the structure defined *could* support duplicated values but given that its calling the list a "set" my guess is that this just isn't allowed:

[image: aws web interface]

What is the best way of doing this in DynamoDB?

Comment: Oh, I also tried the "L" type as well ... also didn't work

Comment: You can't have duplicate data in a set http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html. Consider implementing it as a comma separated string and have a marshalling class to seperate it

Answer (score 2):

The `"L"` data type is what you are looking for. Here is a full example I ran against DynamoDBLocal using *AWS Java SDK version 1.9.3*. There is an immediate `Scan` to check the results of the table (output below code). It should not be any different when using the actual DynamoDB service:

```java
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeDefinition;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.CreateTableRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.CreateTableResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.KeySchemaElement;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.KeyType;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ProvisionedThroughput;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.PutItemRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ScalarAttributeType;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ScanRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ScanResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.util.Tables;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;

import java.util.List;

public class Test28140400 {

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "test_table";
    private static final String HASH_KEY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "hash";
    private static final String RANGE_KEY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "range";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("key", "secret");
        AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDB = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(awsCredentials);
        dynamoDB.setEndpoint("http://localhost:4000");

        if (Tables.doesTableExist(dynamoDB, TABLE_NAME)) {
            dynamoDB.deleteTable(TABLE_NAME);
        }

        CreateTableRequest createTableRequest = new CreateTableRequest();
        createTableRequest.setTableName(TABLE_NAME);
        createTableRequest.setProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(50l, 50l));

        List<KeySchemaElement> keySchema = ImmutableList.<KeySchemaElement>builder()
                .add(new KeySchemaElement(HASH_KEY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, KeyType.HASH))
                .add(new KeySchemaElement(RANGE_KEY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, KeyType.RANGE))
                .build();
        createTableRequest.setKeySchema(keySchema);

        List<AttributeDefinition> attributeDefinitions = ImmutableList.<AttributeDefinition>builder()
              .add(new AttributeDefinition(HASH_KEY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ScalarAttributeType.S))
              .add(new AttributeDefinition(RANGE_KEY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ScalarAttributeType.N))
              .build();
        createTableRequest.setAttributeDefinitions(attributeDefinitions);

        CreateTableResult createTableResult = dynamoDB.createTable(createTableRequest);
        Tables.waitForTableToBecomeActive(dynamoDB, TABLE_NAME);

        PutItemRequest putItemRequest = new PutItemRequest();
        putItemRequest.setTableName(TABLE_NAME);
        putItemRequest.addItemEntry(HASH_KEY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, new AttributeValue().withS("first_hash"));
        putItemRequest.addItemEntry(RANGE_KEY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, new AttributeValue().withN("123456789"));
        // Using the "L" type
        //better, excellent, best, important, good, success, best, creative, powerful, benefits
        List<AttributeValue> attributes = ImmutableList.<AttributeValue>builder()
                .add(new AttributeValue().withS("better"))
                .add(new AttributeValue().withS("excellent"))
                .add(new AttributeValue().withS("best"))
                .add(new AttributeValue().withS("important"))
                .add(new AttributeValue().withS("good"))
                .add(new AttributeValue().withS("success"))
                .add(new AttributeValue().withS("best"))
                .add(new AttributeValue().withS("creative"))
                .add(new AttributeValue().withS("powerful"))
                .add(new AttributeValue().withS("benefits"))
                .build();
        putItemRequest.addItemEntry("random_attribute", new AttributeValue().withL(attributes));
        dynamoDB.putItem(putItemRequest);

        ScanResult scan = dynamoDB.scan(new ScanRequest(TABLE_NAME));
        scan.getItems().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output:

> {random_attribute={L: [{S: better,}, {S: excellent,}, {S: best,}, {S:
>   important,}, {S: good,}, {S: success,}, {S: best,}, {S: creative,},
>   {S: powerful,}, {S: benefits,}],}, range={N: 123456789,}, hash={S:
>   first_hash,}}

Comment: Thanks Mike. I had tried the 'L' type and got an error message which I unfortunately didn't write down but I had thought it had similar text to what I was getting on SS. I've found DynamoDB so frustrating that I decided to just live with a file based JSON solution for now. :^p

Comment: @ken It is definitely a cool platform that takes some learning to get used to. Like in the example I provided, it is pretty easy to just try some stuff in the [`DynamoDBLocal` ](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.DynamoDBLocal.html) if you want to test out some things before trying them against the service!